# Configuring mail on JHipster (Spring) project

Tags: email, jhipster

I know it must be, probably, a very simple question, but I'm stucked at this for many hours I didn't find the problem after lots of research on internet.

I started a jhipster project, and now I'm trying to configure a e-mail server to use for send registration e-mails to my new users. So I edited the 2 configuration files that exist in the project:

../src/test/resources/config/application.yml

../src/main/resources/config/application.yml

In each one of these I added the following lines under "Spring: mail:"

```
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 25
    user: xxx@gmail.com
    password: xxx
    protocol: smtp
    tls: true
    auth: true
    from: xxx@gmail.com
```

Then I tried to make a new registration and didn't work the mail confirmation, I also tried to run a test, calling explicitly the function "sendEmail" from the "mailService", it also didn't work. Someone knows why? Am I making some configuration mistake? There is something else I should make?

Adding the asked info about logs:

Usually this is the log that I get when I run the test which calls the sendMail function:

```
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.CacheConfiguration - No cache<br>
[WARN] org.portotech.perdigao.Application - No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.MailConfiguration - Configuring mail server<br>
[INFO] org.portotech.perdigao.config.ThymeleafConfiguration - loading non-reloadable mail messages resources<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Mongeez<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.service.MailService - Send e-mail[multipart 'false' and html 'false'] to 'xxx@gmail.com' with subject 'test' and content=test<br>
[INFO] org.portotech.perdigao.config.CacheConfiguration - Remove Cache Manager metrics<br>
[INFO] org.portotech.perdigao.config.CacheConfiguration - Closing Cache Manager<br>
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:51831', transport: 'socket'<br>
Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, the email wasn't sent, but I got no error message. After you posted the comment, I opened my IDE again (Intellij) to copy the log to post here and got the following log:

```
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.AsyncConfiguration - Creating Async Task Executor<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.MetricsConfiguration - Registering JVM gauges<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.CacheConfiguration - No cache<br>
[WARN] org.portotech.perdigao.Application - No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.MailConfiguration - Configuring mail server<br>
[INFO] org.portotech.perdigao.config.ThymeleafConfiguration - loading non-reloadable mail messages resources<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.config.DatabaseConfiguration - Configuring Mongeez<br>
[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.service.MailService - Send e-mail[multipart 'false' and html 'false'] to 'xxx@gmail.com' with subject 'test' and content=test<br>
[WARN] org.portotech.perdigao.service.MailService - E-mail could not be sent to user 'xxx@gmail.com', exception is: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection error (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host). Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection error (java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host)<br>
[INFO] org.portotech.perdigao.config.CacheConfiguration - Remove Cache Manager metrics<br>
[INFO] org.portotech.perdigao.config.CacheConfiguration - Closing Cache Manager
```

Then I executed again, and never got that message again, about the NoRouteToHostException, the log is like the first I posted. That's really weird =/. Anyway, i did a ping to smtp.gmail.com and it is ok.

Comment: If this fails, you should have a stacktrace in the log, can you post it?

Comment: Just added the info, hope it help you to help me :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using port 25 and TLS, and TLS uses port 587.

Comment: Thanks, Julien, but I also tried port 587, and it was still didn't working.

Comment: When I try to Sign a user Up by the application using port 587, this is the log I get:

[WARN] org.portotech.perdigao.service.MailService - E-mail could not be sent to user 'xxx@gmail.com', exception is: Mail server connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException: Error in getting welcome msg. Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Error in getting welcome msg

[DEBUG] org.portotech.perdigao.aop.logging.LoggingAspect - Exit: org.portotech.perdigao.service.MailService.sendActivationEmail() with result = null

Comment: After some attempts (also attempted port 465) I find out that is necessary to change a configuration to allow access to less secure apps on the gmail account used to send e-mail. Anyway, it helped to be sure that the right port was 587. Thanks for the helpness.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Just to add, this is the link from where one can change the access of less secure apps on Gmail: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en